# Improve code coverage on model class

Tags: apex, rest-api, code-coverage, apex-webservice

I am working on a making a callout to a third party webservice that provides information about some of the fields on the Accounts. The webservice response is huge and the corresponding model class is also big. Below is the model class that represents the webservice response.

```
public class VModel {
    public class CU {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string cNum {get; set;}
        public string oNum {get; set;}
        public string oTyp {get; set;}
        public string nm {get; set;}
        public string city {get; set;}
        public string state {get; set;}
        public string st {get; set;}
        public string sDate {get; set;}
    }

    public class V {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string nm {get; set;}
        public string al {get; set;}
        public string site {get; set;}
        public string pc {get; set;}
        public Boolean isInactive {get; set;}
    }

    public class PT {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string nm {get; set;}
        public string desc {get; set;}
        public integer so {get; set;}
        public boolean isInactive {get; set;}
    }

    public class PTG {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public PT pt {get; set;}
        public boolean isInactive {get; set;}
    }

    public class CG {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public PTG ptg {get; set;}
        public string val {get; set;}
        public string note {get; set;}
        public boolean isInactive {get; set;}
    }

    public class SC {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public CG cg {get; set;}
        public string val {get; set;}
        public string note {get; set;}
        public boolean isInactive {get; set;}
    }

    public class SM {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string nm {get; set;}
        public string st {get; set;}
        public Boolean isInactive {get; set;}
        public list<SC> sc {get; set;}
    }

    public class VS {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public V v {get; set;}
        public SM sm {get; set;}
        public string nm {get; set;}
        public string al {get; set;}
        public string vt {get; set;}
        public string sc {get; set;}
        public boolean isInactive {get; set;}
        public string ht {get; set;}
    }
    
    public class CUVFS {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public CU cu {get; set;}
        public VS vs {get; set;}

        public PT pt {get; set;}
        public datetime startDate {get; set;}
        public datetime endDate {get; set;}
        public boolean isInactive {get; set;}
    }
}
```

The only fields that are used to derive the field values on the account as VS.name, CUVFS.PT, CUVFS.StartDate and CUVFS.EndDate.

I have created the test class for the actual service class and the code coverage of the service class is around 87%. However, the code coverage on the model class is only around 15% since I am not using majority of the fields in the service class.

How do I improve the code coverage of the model class in this case?

Comment: Do you really need those getters and setters? If you remove them, the line is not considered executable and requires no coverage.

Answer (score 1):

[David Reed's suggestion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331213/improve-code-coverage-on-model-class#comment489682_331213) of switching from properties to member declarations is a good one. As the member declarations aren't considered something that requires code coverage you no longer need to test them.

Another alternative is to use a representative sample JSON payload in a tool like [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/). This will generate a test method that ensures the sample payload can be successfully parsed. Because it only generates members based on the sample payload the coverage should be 100%. It isn't the most elegant test method, but it is sufficient for generated code.